# How to enable search bar in text editor in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, text, editor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXNTr.png)
VS2019

Hi, can you tell me how to turn on this bar in text editor?

Comment: You can always do Ctrl-F. :-)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644839/visual-studio-2015-navigation-bar-disappears

Answer (score 0):

The search bar is from [visual assist](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WholeTomatoSoftware.VisualAssist), which is a paid extension in visual studio.